# Java stream with method references for instanceof and class cast

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

Can I convert the following code using method reference?

```
List<Text> childrenToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

group.getChildren().stream()
    .filter(c -> c instanceof Text)
    .forEach(c -> childrenToRemove.add((Text)c));
```

Let me give an example to illustrate what I mean, suppose we have

```
myList
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> s.startsWith("c"))
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(elem -> System.out.println(elem));
```

using method reference it can be written as (last line)

```
myList
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> s.startsWith("c"))
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

What are the rules to convert an expression to a method reference?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, you can use these method references:

```
.filter(Text.class::isInstance)
.map(Text.class::cast)
.forEach(childrenToRemove::add);
```

Instead of for-each-add, you can collect stream items with [`Collectors.toSet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--):

```
Set<Text> childrenToRemove = group.getChildren()
    // ...
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Use [`toList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) if you need to maintain the order of children.

You can replace lambda expressions with method references if the signatures match by applying these rules:

```
ContainingClass::staticMethodName // method reference to a static method
containingObject::instanceMethodName // method reference to an instance method
ContainingType::methodName // method reference to an instance method
ClassName::new // method reference to a constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

I think yes it's possible, like so

```
group.getChildren()
    .filter(Text.class::isInstance)
    .map(Text.class::cast)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> childrenToRemove));
```